# how to read HttpOnly cookies using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I already tried `document.cookie` and it didn't work. I tried researching but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - thats the whole point of `HttpOnly`

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it is sent only to the server.  For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript, and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks

Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

If your cookie does not contain sensitive info (such as a server-side session) then it should not be marked `HttpOnly`!